# Unicode Language Support in the VBA editor

Tags: excel, vba, internationalization, ms-office

I have a VBA project in Excel 2003.

This VBA project was written in Russian using Cyrillic encoding, so all the comments and messages are unreadable on my English OS (WindowsXP).

so the code on Russian machine looking like (OK):

```
Sub Select_I()
'Выделяет по текущей ячейке "построчный" диапазон для ввода данных по объекту
```

become on mine (NOT OK)

```
Sub Select_I()
'Âûäåëÿåò ïî òåêóùåé ÿ÷åéêå "ïîñòðî÷íûé" äèàïàçîí äëÿ ââîäà äàííûõ ïî îáúåêòó
```

Is there a way to "indicate" to the VBA editor what encoding to use?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround for me - when copy-paste Russian text from VBA editor to somewhere else in Windows and keyboard at that moment is in Russian layout, then pasted Russian symbols are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (I cannot test this very easily but it should work):

Control Panel --> Date, Time, Language, and Regional Options --> Regional and Language Options --> Advanced

and set the language for non-Unicode programs to the appropriate language (Russian it seems in your case).